# How to install haskell Parallel on mac?

Tags: haskell, installation, parallel-processing, cabal

How to install haskell Parallel on mac?
I'm trying:  '$sudo cabal install parallel' but its not working. I'm getting the following message:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring parallel-3.2.0.0...
Preprocessing library parallel-3.2.0.0...
Building parallel-3.2.0.0...
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id deepseq-1.1.0.2-09b3aed0c4982bbc6569c668100876fa
    (use -v for more information)
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
parallel-3.2.0.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is deepseq in the user db? Then it's not available for global installs (what the sudo suggests you're trying). Otherwise, what does `cabal install -v parallel` tell you?

Comment: lots of things, but it ends like this:
'cabal: /Users/Filipe/Library/Haskell/logs/build.log: permission denied'
If you need i can post the rest of the message for you. Thanks!

Comment: `permission denied`, was that with or without sudo? What happens if you try without build log?

Comment: yes, thats without the sudo. Is '-v'the option to build log? if it is, I'm getting this:
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring parallel-3.2.0.0...
Preprocessing library parallel-3.2.0.0...
Building parallel-3.2.0.0...
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id deepseq-1.1.0.2-09b3aed0c4982bbc6569c668100876fa
    (use -v for more information)
cabal: /Users/Filipe/Library/Haskell/logs/build.log: permission denied

Comment: No, -v means 'be verbose'. The build-summary (not log, although the file is named build.log :() is independent of that. You can tell it to log the build elsewhere with `--build-summary=TEMPLATE`, I'm not sure whether you can completely disable it, though.

Comment: What's the output of `ghc-pkg check`?  It seems like there's a user/global package db issue, and also maybe some permissions problems.

Comment: I reinstalled GHC and its all working fine now. Parallel install whent just fine. Thanks.